# Find the order of $\langle (1,1)\rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, direct-product

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills. 1 generates $\mathbb{Z}_2$, and likewise generates $\mathbb{Z}_4$. So shouldn't (1,1) generate the whole thing? Yet I keep running up against

$\langle (1,1) \rangle = \{ (1,1), (0,2), (1,3), (0,0) \} $

which is order 4. $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ is clearly order 8.

I looked at other examples on here to see if I was generating $\langle (1,1) \rangle$ correctly, and I THINK I am.... Am I not?

Comment: From the fact that 1 generates Z2 and Z4 you can only conclude that $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ generates the product.

Comment: The product of cyclic groups is not necessarily cyclic.

Comment: Pretty sure the order is $4$. The element $(1,2)$ can not be generated by your $(1,1)$

Comment: you did it right but note that while the second 1 is trying to generate the second group the first group was done.

Comment: So it seems I was just confused about what is required for an element to generate the cross product. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indeed writing $\langle (1,1) \rangle$ correctly, and no: $(1,1)$ does not (on its own) generate $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_4$.

In fact, $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_4$ is not generated by *any* single element, which is to say it is not *cyclic*. In general, $\Bbb Z_m\times \Bbb Z_n$ will be cyclic if and only if $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

Comment: I actually knew that one. I guess it was the crazy pills. Thank you! EDIT: So if it was Z11 x Z15, then (1,1) would be a generator, and the factor group (Z11 x Z15)/(<(1,1)>) would be order 1.... ?

Comment: @Indigo yes, that's right.  In particular, since $\langle (1,1) \rangle = G$, your factor group is $G/G$, which is just the trivial group.

Comment: So, then, say we had $\mathbb{Z}_{12} / \langle 4 \rangle$, and wanted the order of an element $5+\langle 4\rangle$? Since $\langle 4\rangle$ is order 3, wouldn't any element of the factor group also be order 3?

Comment: @Indigo not *any* element, surely $0 + \langle 4 \rangle$ has order $1$. But yes, the non-identity elements of a (cyclic) group of prime order $p$ have order $p$.

Comment: I don't understand why $0+\langle 4 \rangle$ is order 1, if $\langle 4 \rangle$ itself is order 3.

Comment: Oh, I mispoke earlier. Note that $\Bbb Z_{12} / \langle 4 \rangle$ has order $4 = 12/3$.  First of all, note that the elements $m + \langle 4 \rangle$ are elements of the group $\Bbb Z_{12}/\langle 4 \rangle$, **not** the group $\langle 4 \rangle$. This quotient group (factor group) has order $4$.

Comment: Now, note that **the order of a group** and **the order of an element** (of a group) are two very different things.  Do you know the difference?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32393/discussion-between-indigo-and-omnomnomnom).

Comment: In any case, $0 + \langle 4 \rangle$ has order $1$ because it is the identity element of the quotient group.

Answer (score 4):

Further to another answer, it is easy to convince yourself that:
" The order of element $(a,b)\in Z_{n}\times Z_{m}$ is the l.c.m of the orders of $a$ and $b$ in their groups respectively"